# Question about atoms

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

For a finite algebra $F$ a set $A\in F$ is called an atom if $B\in F$, B isn't empty and $B\subset A$ implies $B=A$. I have to show that for a finite algebra $F$ the set of atoms forms a partition of $\Omega$.

For showing that $A_{i}\cap A_{j}=\emptyset$, I want to derive a contradiciton. I thought something like:

Suppose $A_{i}\cap A_{j}\neq \emptyset$. Then there exists a $B$ such that $B\subset A_{i}$ and $B\subset A_{j}$. 
From the definition of atoms it follow that $B=A_{i}$ and $B=A_{j}$. So $A_{i}=A_{j}$, so $A_{i}\cap A_{j}$=$B$. But this isn't a contradiction. I have also troubles with showing that the union of $A_{i}\in F$ equals $\Omega$.

Comment: Well: $A_i\cap A_j \subseteq A_i$, so if the intersection isn't empty and both sets are atoms, then both sets are not distinct.  Hence distinct atoms must be disjoint.  That is all.

Answer (score 1):

Well, what you already got: if the atom $A_i$ intersects $A_j$, then $A_i=A_j$. 
So, this is just what we wanted: any two *different* atoms of the set algebra are disjoint.

For fullness, suppose $A_1,\dots,A_k$ are different atoms, then consider $B:=(A_1\cup\dots\cup A_k)^\complement$. If $B=\emptyset$ or $B$ is an atom, we are ready. Else, we have some $\emptyset\neq B_1\subsetneq B$. Because our set algebra is *finite*, we can choose a smallest such $B_1$. Can you finish from here?

Comment: Thanks for the first part! Why are we ready if B is an atom? Unfortunately I see don't see the finishing part..

Comment: Well, $\Omega=A_1\cup\dots\cup A_k\cup B$. So if $B$ is an atom, we already get a union of atoms. For finishing the proof, assume that the set $\{A_1,\dots,A_k\}$ of atoms is *maximal*. Then the existence of atom $B_1\subseteq B$ would contradict this assumption. Finiteness of the algebra is heavily used.